# Code First custom database initialization being skipped

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to seed my database using a custom initializer, but the code in the global.asax seems to just completely skip it. Here's my code. I'm using asp.net MVC 4.

Global.asax:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DbInitializer());
```

Custom initializer:

```
public class DbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<IAMContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(IAMContext context)
    {
        context.Products.Add( new Product { blah blah blah});
        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

I've put breakpoints inside the DbInitializer and it doesn't even seem to make it there. What should I do, great stackoverflow?

Comment: You have this tagged as `Code-first-migrations` yet you are using `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` , which one is it? if you are using migrations you should be using `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I'm new to code first and I thought they were the same. I removed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to restart IIS Express to get the application to restart.